# Checkystyle issue in ActionListener: Reference to instance variable 'x' needs 'this.' in Java

Tags: java, actionlistener, checkstyle

At first I am beginner in Java. I have problem with checkstyle error mentioned in thread title.

Consider having similiar code:

```
public class myClass {
  JButton[] buttons;

      public myClass() {
        this.buttons = new JButton[2];
        //constructor code....

        this.buttons[0].addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {                  
                      firstMethod(0, 1);
                      secondMethod(5, 10);
                    }
                });

      }

      public void firstMethod( int x, int y ) {
        // do something

     }

      public void secondMethod( int x, int y ) {
        // do something

     }

    }
```

In constructior I've created onclick event for button from attribute `buttons`, where when the button is clicked it will perform method `firstMethod(int, int)` and `secondMethod(int, int)`, everything working of course, but the checkstyle throws me the error.
For some reasons I cannot just use `this.firstMethod()` as I am inside another object (ActionListener).

Any ideas how to throw myClass reference into actionListener?

Comment: Possibly, but checkstyle error is not mentioned in the post you posted so I didnt find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new ActionListener() { ... };` block actually creates a new anonymous class. Inside that block, `this` refers to the `ActionListener`. To refer to the outer `myClass` object, use `myClass.this`.

Comment: Yes, thats the thing I was looking for. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `myClass.this` instead of plain `this` to refer to the outer class instance. Also use uppercase for classes, so `MyClass`, not `myClass`.

Comment: Yes I know, I made a mistake while writing quick example. Thanks for answer.